# How can stylesheet auto-linking be stopped in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, asset-pipeline, sprockets

By default, (at least, using scaffolding), Rails adds links to all stylesheets in the `/app/assets/stylesheets` directory.  I'd like to have multiple smaller stylesheets for organization, but only need to link to one that imports the rest in order to stay organized yet minimize HTTP requests.

Is there a way to disable this auto-inclusion, whether by configuring the asset pipeline or changing how they're included in the layout itself?

FWIW, I'm including the main stylesheet from `application.html.haml` using `stylesheet_link_tag "application"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by modifying your **application.css(.scss)** file.

In that file there will be the following line:

```
require_tree .
```

Simply remove that and replace it with the includes you require.

**application.css**

```
require file1
require nested/folders/file2
```

Then you can have another file

**main.css**

```
require file2
require file3
```

And include them separately:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "application"  
stylesheet_link_tag "main"
```

The stylesheet_link_tag can take an array too, if for some reason you want the css files to load in the same place, but with separate HTTP requests.

```
stylesheet_link_tag ["application", "main"]
```

The files with the requires are called [manifest files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).